# How to add and position new ViewPart programmatically from another view or handler?

Tags: java, eclipse, view, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I know I can create new views by `plugin.xml`. Also I can create new views by `IPerpspectiveFactory.createInitialLayout(IPageLayout)` with code like

```
layout.addView(ChatView.ID, IPageLayout.LEFT, 1.0f, editorArea);
```

Is it possible to do the same from another view by command?

Also my view is not singleton, so I wish to create view copies.

Unfortunately, with code like

```
HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getActivePage().showView(viewId);
```

I have no ability to define view position within a layout. I woould like to pass all new views to layout folder.

**UPDATE**

I have modified the perspective code the following way:

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {

        String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();

        layout.addView(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW, IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.75f, editorArea);

        layout.addView(CoreSettingsView.ID, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f, editorArea);

        //layout.addView(ChatView.ID, IPageLayout.LEFT, 1.0f, editorArea);

        IFolderLayout folder = layout.createFolder("chatfolder", IPageLayout.LEFT, 1.0f, editorArea);
        folder.addPlaceholder(ChatView.ID);
    }
```

Commented line previously was causing that chat view appeared in the "main" region of perspective.

Now I changed it according to advices to have placeholder in the same place.

The code of handler's execute is follows:

```
@Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        try {
            ChatView chatView = (ChatView) HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getActivePage().showView(
                    ChatView.ID, 
                    Integer.toString(counter++), 
                    IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE);

        } catch (PartInitException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return event;
    }
```

this causes new view appear, but they all appear in the same place as console view located. I.e. not that place it was appearing when positioned directly.

Why?

**UPDATE 2**

This is is picture about how it happens with placeholder. Red arrows show where new views actually appear if green button pressed. Blue arrow shows where views should appear and where it (one instance) actually appears if explicitly positioned in perspective:

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

The following worked:

```
    IFolderLayout folder = layout.createFolder("chatfolder", IPageLayout.LEFT, 1.0f, editorArea);
    folder.addPlaceholder(ChatView.ID + ":*");
```

Also I used 1.0f despite 0.95f is considered to be a maximum. If I use 0.95f then not full area is occupied.

Comment: The position `ratio` parameter must be in range `0.05f` to `0.95f`. You have used `1.0f` for the folder which is invalid.

Comment: It worked with explicit view. Also I need to occupy entire area.

Comment: Changing to 0.95f didn't fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add placeholders when you create your initial layout. After that, from other views, you just show the view you want to show. It will turn up in the placeholder for it.

[See 9.2 Perspective](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse3RCP/article.html)

Comment: Why do you say I define only placeholders? In result of this definition, a view appears and `ViewPart` class instantiated. If you are right, then how to prevent view appearance until I explicitly show it by command?

Answer (score 1):

You can open several views with the same id by using a unique `secondary id` for each view and using

```
IWorkbenchPage.showView(viewId, secondardId, IWorbenchPage.VEW_ACTIVATE);
```

All the views will be placed in the folder defined for the view id.

You would do something like this in the perspective factory to set this up:

```
IFolderLayout folder = layout.createFolder(folderId, IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.75f, layout.getEditorArea());

folder.addPlaceholder(viewId);
```

Comment: Where the folder is defined?

Comment: This is an `IFolderLayout` in the perspective `IPageLayout`

Comment: Sorry, I meant, how to define folder for a view id? Method `org.eclipse.ui.IPageLayout.createFolder(String, int, float, String)` contains only folder id. Is this the same as view id?

Comment: Added folder setup to answer

Comment: It didn't worked for me if I implement it correctly. Please see my update.